# FFMPEG build not able to recognize image file on Android

Tags: android, image, ffmpeg, video-capture

I am trying to convert a series of images to video on Android. I have successfully built [Guardian Project](https://github./guardianproject/android-ffmpeg). Now when I try to run this command

```
/data/data/com.mobvcasting.mjpegffmpeg/ffmpeg -r 4 -i /mnt/sdcard/RAS/img/file%03d.bmp -r /mnt/sdcard/RAS/img/demoFile.mp4"
```

i get an error saying

```
10-02 05:48:35.247: V/PROJECT_NAME(13972): ***/mnt/sdcard/RAS/img/file%03d.bmp: No such file or directory***
```

I have images at /mnt/sdcard/RAS/img/ directory starting from file000.bmp.

I even tried changing my command to

```
/data/data/com.mobvcasting.mjpegffmpeg/ffmpeg -r 4 -i /mnt/sdcard/RAS/img/file000.bmp -r /mnt/sdcard/RAS/img/demoFile.mp4"
```

to get the same error again.

Also, it is able to recognize /mnt/sdcard/RAS/img/ as a directory.
What can I change to get rid of the error message?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you got the solution of that problem. If yes please share.

Comment: Please share if you got any solution for this problem